# Like operator on SOQL

Tags: soql

Is there any difference in performance with Like'%abc' and Like 'abc%'? For example, if I write

```
List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id from account where name like'abc%'];
List<Account> acc1 = [SELECT Id from account where name like'%abc'];
```

Comment: They both return completely different query results, one is `starts with` other is `ends with` wild card search. Performance of both would be different based on the record set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference in performance I know is when the field is indexed.
The standard field Name is indexed by default.

In this [document](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/doc/en-us/static/pdf/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf), you can see that for the operation `LIKE`, Force.com tests for conditions that don't start with a leading
wildcard the first 100,000 rows for selectivity.

We can say that, in certain cases, your first query having `like'abc%'` can be more performant than `like'%abc'`